# Transform comma separated string into separate rows in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame that looks like this:

```
user   |  items 
--------------------------------------
user1  | apple, bread, cheese, orange
user2  | apple, corn, strawberry, squash
  .    |  . 
  .    |  .
  .    |  .
```

Final dataFrame should look like:

```
user   |  items 
--------------------------------------
user1  | apple
user1  | bread
user1  | cheese
user1  | orange
user2  | apple
user2  | corn
user2  | strawberry
user2  | squash 
  .    |   .
  .    |   .
  .    |   .
```

How would I transform the original dataFrame into the final dataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split`, e.g.,

```
import pandas as pd
df['Skills'] = df['Skills'].str.split(',')
df.explode('Skills', ignore_index=True)
```

and you will obtain something like

```
   Name      Skills
0  John      Python
1  John        Java
2  Jane         C++
3  Jane  JavaScript
4   Jim        HTML
5   Jim         CSS
```

## data

```
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Jim'],
        'Skills': ['Python,Java', 'C++,JavaScript', 'HTML,CSS']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

shown as

```
   Name          Skills
0  John     Python,Java
1  Jane  C++,JavaScript
2   Jim        HTML,CSS
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect your original dataframe is called `df`

```
# Split the items and create a new DataFrame
new_df = df['items'].str.split(', ').explode().reset_index(drop=True)

# Create a DataFrame with the 'user' column repeated for each item
user_col = df['user'].repeat(df['items'].str.count(', ') + 1).reset_index(drop=True)

# Combine the user and items columns to get the final DataFrame
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'user': user_col, 'items': new_df})
```

I hope this is what you looked for.

Answer (score 0):

First you can split your items with `,`

Then the user column will have list values

| index | user | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | user1 | [apple, bread, cheese, orange] |
| 1 | user2 | [apple, corn, strawberry, squash] |

After you can transform list values into row replicating index values using [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode)

```
df = df.explode('items').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: How is this different from the other two answers?